# Trigonometrical Question

Tags: trigonometry

the question is solve the following equation in the interval 
 
$$0<\theta\leq 360$$
$$\tan(\theta) = \tan(\theta)(2+3\sin(\theta))$$

I got 199.5 and 340.5 as my answers like so:

$\tan(\theta) = \tan(\theta)(2+3\sin(\theta))$
$1=2+3\sin(\theta)$
$\sin(-1/3) = 199.5$ and $340.4$

However in the answer scheme it gives 180, 199.5, 340.5 and 360
How do they get the 2 extra values?

Comment: You forgot the solutions with $\tan\theta=0$.

Comment: include solution of $\tan\theta=0$

Comment: how did you get $tan(\theta)=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\tan\theta=0$, the equation obviously holds. That gives the solutions $180^\circ$ and $360^\circ$. We can only "cancel" $\tan\theta$ if $\tan\theta\ne 0$. When we cancel, we are potentially throwing away some roots.

When we cancel, we get $1=2+3\sin\theta$, or equivalently $\sin\theta=-\frac{1}{3}$. This has the solutions that you found.

Let's look at a related example, $x=x(x^2-3)$. This has the obvious solution $x=0$. For $x\ne 0$, the equation is equivalent to $1=x^2-3$, which has the solutions $x=\pm 2$.

**Remark:** Instead of immediately cancelling, we could rewrite the equation as $\tan\theta(+3\sin\theta)-\tan\theta=0$, or equivalently as $\tan\theta(1+3\sin\theta)=0$. A product is $0$ **if and only if** one of the terms is $0$. This gives us the possibilities $\tan\theta=0$ and $1+3\sin\theta=0$.

"Cancelling" is quicker, but carries a risk of throwing away some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The $\theta = 180$ answer is the "trivial solution".  If you plug in $\theta=180$ or 360 you immediately get zeroes on both sides.